# props showing empty array - React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning React on my own. I have a couple of questions. I'm trying to fetch data to another component. I've tried to `setState` after mapping JSON data. But it was showing an error “`setState is not a function`”.

1. How can I `setState` after mapping JSON data?

   ```
   // Fetching data and passing JSON values to TabBarMenu component

   export default class App extends Component {
       state = {
         temp: [],
         description: [],
         time: []
       };

   _getFiveWeather = (lat, lng) => {    
       fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&APPID=${API_KEY}`)
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(json => json.list.map(function(item) {
             return (
               <TabBarMenu key={item.dt_txt} time={item.dt_txt} description={item.weather.description} />
             );
           })
   }}
   ```

In `TabBarMenu.js`, I'm trying to pass the `props` (time, description) to the `_FirstRoute`. When I did `console.log(this.props),` it shows empty array.

2. How can I grab the `props` value from the constructor?

   I really appreciate your help.

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
   import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

   export default class TabBarMenu extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       console.log(this.props) // showing empty array

       this.state = {
         index: 0,
         routes: [
           { key: '1', title: 'Weather' },
           { key: '2', title: 'News' },
           { key: '3', title: 'Photos' },
         ],
       };
     }

     _FirstRoute = this.props => (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text style={styles.textStyle}>1</Text>
         <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.time}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.temp}</Text>
       </View>
     )...
   ```

Comment: Does the TabBarMenu render? You need to render your _getFiveWeather function, but this might be more so bad design because you're trying to do too much in the _getFiveWeather function. Separate a fetching method and a rendering method so you can set the state of the json. Please note: you can't set state in the render method else this will cause **INFINITE** rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_getFiveWeather` definition is essentially useless because after fetching data, you are not really doing anything with the mapped components. You just do the map operation and then that's it -- nothing else is happening.

That method that fetches data should be concerned only with that -- fetching data; it should have nothing to do with generating components. You should set the state with the new data after fetching it. Something like `this.setState({ ... })` after successful fetching the info.

Then, in the `render()` method, you verify if there is anything to render. That is, if there is any weather information in your component state properties, you do some sort of mapping to dynamically create the components you need to render.

Nowhere did I see the render() method in your code, so I think you should focus on learning the basics. Start with render(). Don't try to do too many things at once.